# ajax loaded content with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried to solve this problem and i am quite helpless now.

I am loading data into a div via Ajax with:

```
function sk_upload_l()
{

var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("ajax_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",".../sk_upload_request.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Inside of the div is an input field loaded to which auto-completition should be applied to.

The input field:

```
<input name="tags" id="tags" size="60">
```

The complete-Code is:

```
$(function() {
function log( message ) {
  $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#tags" );
  $( "#tags" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}


$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: "search_tags.php",
  minLength: 1,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
  }
});
```

});

I can't get the auto-complete getting to work in the new loaded div field.

Sadly I even don't know if it is possible to achieve this with that code (i don't want to drop the sk_upload_l() because i have more (complex functions like that))

I tried to call the auto-complete function in the '$( document ).ready(function()' and also the call the auto-complete function i in the Ajax function (after xmlhttp.send();) which both didn't work.

The auto-complete code without the Ajax call works fine and i don't know if its even possible to achieve auto-complete with the Ajax call i have now :(

Any hints are welcome.

thanks & best regards
Dave

Comment: If you're using jQuery why aren't you using jQuery's `$.ajax`?

Comment: You might want to take a look of this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say that the autocomplete is pointing toward a div, yet the source: for the autocomplete is a php file. Does the php file return a JSON array? I have code for using the contents of a div as a source for autocomplete, and also code for returning JSON data with a PHP file, but I'm not sure which you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with calling the ac code at the end of the ajax call.

thx for all the helpful answers